# Up Button in ActionBar with the possibility to move more activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I'm doing an app for Android. In the DetailActivity, there is the ActionBar with the Up Button. When I press it, it would return in the previous activity. But the DetailActivity can be launched from different activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent)` , you can just use `finish()` or `onBackPressed()`. This would finish the activity, and go back to the previous one. So handling of the Up button being pressed would look like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the method "onBackPressed",but the UpButton in the ActionBar. I already know the string containg the class to be launched thanks to SharedPreferences. How can i do??

Comment: When you press the up button, you want to go back to the previous activity, right? What do you want to launch then, and when?

Comment: I have three Activity that can be launch the DetailActivity. In the DetailActivity i want go back to the previous.

Comment: So when you call finish() (or onBackPressed()), in the DetailActivity, it will go back to the previous one. You don't need to launch them, they will be stored in the backstack.

Comment: I have disabled the back button. But finish() does exactly what??

Comment: It destroys your activity, and goes back to the previous one.
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()

Comment: A lot of thanks. Please you wait a few minutes. I now make a test